# Learn C The Hard Way, Ex20 - Makefile Issue?

Tags: c, makefile, valgrind

I've been following Zed Shaw's Learn C The Hard Way, and I've gotten to exercise 20, which can be viewed here:  http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex20.html . I'm using Linux Mint KDE on VirtualBox, I write code in gedit, and I write makefiles in Kate (for syntactical reasons - I kept having errors in gedit).

After having some errors compiling the code, I simply copied and pasted it, directly, to see if I'd simply not typed it out correctly, but I still had, using Valgrind, the following error output:

```
valgrind make ex20
==2715== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2715== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2715== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2715== Command: make ex20
==2715== 
cc -Wall        -g      -DNDEBUG    ex20.c   -o ex20
In file included from ex20.c:1:0:
dbg.h:1:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef __dbg_h__
 ^
ex20.c: In function ‘test_debug’:
ex20.c:9:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘debug’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     debug("I have Brown Hair.");
     ^
ex20.c: In function ‘test_log_err’:
ex20.c:17:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘log_err’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     log_err("I believe everything is broken.");
     ^
ex20.c: In function ‘test_log_warn’:
ex20.c:23:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘log_warn’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     log_warn("You can safely ignore this.");
     ^
ex20.c: In function ‘test_log_info’:
ex20.c:29:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘log_info’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     log_info("Well I did something mundane.");
     ^
ex20.c: In function ‘test_check’:
ex20.c:39:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘check_mem’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     check_mem(block); // should work
     ^
ex20.c:42:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘check’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     check(input, "Failed to open %s.", file_name);
     ^
ex20.c:48:1: warning: label ‘error’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 error:
 ^
ex20.c: In function ‘test_sentinel’:
ex20.c:64:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sentinel’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             sentinel("I shouldn't run.");
             ^
ex20.c:70:1: warning: label ‘error’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 error:
 ^
ex20.c: In function ‘test_check_mem’:
ex20.c:83:1: warning: label ‘error’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 error:
 ^
ex20.c: In function ‘test_check_debug’:
ex20.c:90:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘check_debug’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     check_debug(i != 0, "Oops, I was 0.");
     ^
ex20.c:93:1: warning: label ‘error’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 error:
 ^
ex20.c: In function ‘main’:
ex20.c:115:1: warning: label ‘error’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 error:
 ^
make: *** [ex20] Error 1
==2715== 
==2715== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2715==     in use at exit: 79,052 bytes in 1,433 blocks
==2715==   total heap usage: 3,370 allocs, 1,937 frees, 205,837 bytes allocated
==2715== 
==2715== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2715==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2715==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2715==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2715==    still reachable: 79,052 bytes in 1,433 blocks
==2715==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2715== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2715== 
==2715== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2715== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Based on the output listed from his make, I decided the Makefile should be as follows:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall    -g  -DNDEBUG

all: ex20   

clean:
    rm  -f  ex20
```

If anyone can explain the cause of the error (beyond defining what an implicitly defined function is--I know that) I'm getting, and how to avoid similar errors, I'd be grateful.  Thank you.

Comment: Why are you running `make` under `valgrind`?  You use `valgrind` for debugging your compilable programs.  You're not yet ready to debug `make` itself.  Please show your source code, and the errors you get from compiling it, disentangled from `valgrind`.

Comment: And the (first — and therefore immediately major) problem is in the first message: `dbg.h:1:0: error: unterminated #ifndef` which points at a line
`#ifndef __dbg_h__`.  It means you've mistranscribed `dbg.h` and forgotten `#endif /* __dbg_h__*/` at the end of the file, or you've mangled that line somehow.  That might account for the missing function declaration warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `#endif` at the end of the file starting with `#ifndef` (`dbg.h`).

```
ex20.c:64:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sentinel’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                 sentinel("I shouldn't run.");
```

To resolve this kind of error you should add the prototype of your function at the top of your .c file or in a .h file. 
See [Function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype)

```
ex20.c:93:1: warning: label ‘error’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
     error:
```

It's pretty clear you defined a label `error:` but you didn't use it.

Comment: Thanks. 
I don't know how I missed that one.

Comment: @JordonBirk: If this answer solved everything, please accept this answer by clicking on the grey tick mark under the votes of the question. If it turns green, it means that this answer is accepted. Doing this will show that this answer is solving your problem, and also will fetch you both some reputation,

Answer (score 0):

First things first, as has been mentioned in the comments, you dont need to run make from within valgrind - not unless you are actually debugging / testing make itself, so to build your program you can just do this:

`make ex20`

and then you can run it:

`./ex20`

or run it under valgrind:

`valgrind ./ex20`

You could, if you wanted, add a rule to the makefile to run for you like so:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall    -g  -DNDEBUG

all: ex20   

run: ex20
    ./ex20

grind: ex20
    valgrind ./ex20

clean:
    rm  -f  ex20
```

Note this doesn't include the recipe to actually build ex20 - that isnt shown in your question either though

Secondly, we can still see the compiler errors. The primary rule with fixing compiler errors and warnings is start at the top, and the first error here is

```
In file included from ex20.c:1:0:
dbg.h:1:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef __dbg_h__
```

This is actually quite informative. We can see that dbg.h uses include guards to prevent against the same header being included more than once by a single .c file, however it looks like there is no terminating `#endif`. The typical structure is like this

```
#ifndef __headername_h
#define __headername_h
//Lots of header content
#endif
```

You can probably fix this by adding a #endif at the end of the file, but it is possible that something has got out of sync further up. But if the header file doesnt end in #endif, that is almost certainly the problem.

Fix that, and recompile. You might find the other warnings/errors go away - who knows what the impact of the first error was. If not figure out what header file the functions are in, and include it.

The unused label may also be a side effect of the first error. The :error label in the code is used by the debug macros.